# Spring data + Mongodb + query single value?

Tags: spring, mongodb

how to query a field instead of a whole object? I am trying to do something like that, want to see is that possible?

```
public BigInteger findUserIDWithRegisteredEmail(String email){

    Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("primaryEmail").is (email));    
    query.fields().include("_id");

    return (BigInteger) mongoTemplate.find(query, BigInteger.class);    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In method

```
find(Query query, Class<YourCollection> entityClass)
```

**entityClass** should be the corresponding collection, not the type of id.

If you are just trying to get id use

```
Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("primaryEmail").is (email));    
query.fields().include("_id");
mongoTemplate.find(query, <YourCollection>.class).getId();
```

If you only include _id, all the other fields will be null in your result.

Comment: Thanks gTito, my thought was trying to save the query time and bandwidth to only retrieve what I need instead of the whole object. so is that mean you have to get the whole document (row) instead of a field or by doing "query.fields().include("_id");" is actually doing so?

Comment: Please note that from db only one field is returned. It is spring-data that copies the value to the field and returns as object. Your query time will be less if you include only one field. But one thing you cannot avoid is the time taken for serialization.

Comment: ah that is what i am trying to avoid the serialization. like if I use ORM / hibernate, i can use direct sql to query just one field instead an object so i guess in java nosql i can't? or is there anything that like sql?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid serialization, this is one way you could handle it:-

```
final List<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
mongoTemplate.executeQuery(query, "collectionName", new DocumentCallbackHandler() {
    @Override
    public void processDocument(DBObject dbObject) throws MongoException, DataAccessException {
        ids.add(dbObject.get("_id").toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: This is interesting, though in my tests it was an order of magnitude slower than the solution posted by @titogeo!